# Can I apply similarity models to .tif files in R?

Tags: r, statistics, raster, similarity

Basically, I have two groups of .tif files (some for Spain and some other for California), and I want to statistically compare the climatic variables (max, min and mean T, and Monthly rainfall) in some coordinates in California and get the most similar coordinates in Spain.

I know this can be done and I think it shouldn't be that hard because I have already done it with proper dataframes, but I'm a bit lost at this point since I know .tif files contain data , but I don't know how to extract them to work in statistics.

I tried extracting California data (which is way smaller because I only have 16 points) into a dataframe with coordinates and variables, but I just don't know any code to compare every row in the dataframe with the .TIF object of Spain and return the most similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint to get you started

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("file.tif")
d <- as.data.frame(x)
```